# FTP folder to local using PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I want to make a copy of ftp in a folder of my project(localhost) so I need to specify source_folder and dest_folder. My problem is that my code just save all files in my project's root and I would like to copy my ftp folder "/" into my "./copy_data" folder in my local project.

Here is my code:

```
 function ftp_sync ($dir) {

    if ($dir != ".") {
        if (ftp_chdir($this->conn, $dir) == false) {
            echo ("Change Dir Failed: $dir<BR>\r\n");
            return;
        }
        if (!(is_dir($dir)))
            mkdir($dir);
        chdir ($dir);
    }

    $contents = ftp_nlist($this->conn, ".");
    foreach ($contents as $file) {

        if ($file == '.' || $file == '..')
            continue;

        if (@ftp_chdir($this->conn, $file)) {
            ftp_chdir ($this->conn, "..");
            $this->ftp_sync ($file);
        }
        else{
            //ftp_get($this->conn, $file, $file, FTP_BINARY);
            ftp_get($this->conn, $file, $file, FTP_BINARY);
        }

    }

    ftp_chdir ($this->conn, "..");
    chdir ("..");

}


    ftp_sync('.');
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: well, you just have to change into that exiting folder locally inside your ftp session. Then the ftp get will place the files in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute bash command from php to zip, copy and move the target folder is my recommendation

```
$message=shell_exec("/var/www/scripts/testscript 2>&1");
print_r($message);
```

Comment: Why would you want to first download to the wrong position, then zip and move and unzip all files? Why not store at the final position right away?